# Best Data Transport Layer

Tags: vb.net, networking, data-transfer, transport

I have made a peer to peer program in TCP then merged to UDP. I would like to change it so you can send files, however UDP does not support this and TCP is slower than TCP. Due to the fact that these are the most common Data Transport Layers, I was curious to learn about any other layers that I do not know about.

So what other layers are there that would work with VB.net?

Comment: Why do you think UDP doesn't support transferring files? For instance, TFTP uses UDP to transfer files. It is harder since you need to handle things in you application that TCP automatically handles for you, but it is done all the time.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably use HTTP for this. 
The things you are thinking about inventing is already invented there.

This could be good starting points for your server side:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener(VS.80).aspx

And the client:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx